# Old Website Address Still Showing

Tags: multisite

I had 'theshortfilm.co" before changing to my current url 'welovefilm.co'. I changed my address 6 months back, everything went fine. But now when I activated my networks, I get my old url in the code. Please see the image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/phqM3.jpg

But when I change the url manually to new address and add it to the wp-config file, I get an error saying website is on infinite redirect loop.

Please help me fix this issue.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly is the problem that you're having but hopefully this solution will work.

1. Backup your database (**This is very important**)
2. Download this script: http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/
3. Use it to replace the old url "theshortfilm.co" to the newer one "welovefilm.co"
4. Remove all the url-related configurations you did in your "wp-config.php"
5. Go to admin panel to the same "enabling the network page" & this time you'll see your new url inside the configuration. Copy this new configuration & put it in `.htaccess` & `wp-config.php` replacing the previous one (if any)
   6) Test to see if your site works, if it does, congrats. If it doesn't, use the backup you took in step one to undo anything you did just now & then try someone else's answer.

**Note:** All this script does is search for a string in the database and replace it with another. You need to be extremely careful when using it. If it says "modified 0 rows", then you most likely put in the wrong url. For best results, include the `http://`.

That file gives database access to anyone who can view it, so **don't use it on production server & immediately delete it after use**

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing is not such complex as you made it. I think no such coding is needed. To make a try, revert the codes you altered as it was before. Then, get into the admin panel `/wp-admin`.

In `Settings > General` tab change the WordPress address (URL) and Site Address (URL) to your desired one.

And then check whether it's ok or not.

Comment: I think my question was not clear. URL changing was successful and this was 6 months back. But now when trying to activate multisite, wordpress is giving me the old url. So when I add the code given to the config file site forwards me to 'theshortfilm.co'. 

Does this have something to do with database of server?

Comment: Have you checked you `.htaccess` configurations?